# Contradictory encoding specifications of Chinese characters when using Python to web scrape

Tags: python, encoding, web-scraping

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape data from a Chinese online publishing website, and this is the URL to one of the novels http://www.jjwxc.net/onebook.php?novelid=1485737.

I have tried different encoding and decoding schemes (e.g., gb2312, utf-8) and their combinations to read the website. For example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.jjwxc.net/onebook.php?novelid=1485737"
response =  requests.get(url)
text = response.text 

print text.encode('gb2312')
>> UnicodeEncodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't encode character u'\xa1' in position 340: illegal multibyte sequence

print text.encode('utf-8')
>> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        <title>¡¶£¨Õý°æ£©±¼ÔÂ¡·Êñ¿Í_¡¾Ô­´´Ð¡Ëµ|ÑÔÇéÐ¡Ëµ¡¿_½ú½­ÎÄÑ§³Ç</title>
                <meta name="Keywords" content="Êñ¿Í,£¨Õý°æ£©±¼ÔÂ,Êñ¿Í¡¶£¨Õý°æ£©±¼ÔÂ¡·,Ö÷½Ç£ºÁøÉÒ ©§ Åä½Ç£ºÔÂ£¬Â½Àë£¬ËÕÐÅ£¬°×ÒÂÚ­ÄÇ£¬Âå¸è£¬×¿ÇïÏÒ£¬ÉÌÓñÈÝ£¬Ð»ÁîÆëµÈµÈ£¨³ö³¡ÅÅÃû£© ©§ ÆäËü£ºÏÉÏÀ£¬ÁøÉÒ£¬ÔÂÉñ£¬Éñ»°,ÇéÓÐ¶ÀÖÓ Å°ÁµÇéÉî ÁéÒìÉñ¹Ö âêÈ»ÈôÊ§ ×îÐÂ¸üÐÂ:2015-07-15 23:57:04 ×÷Æ·»ý·Ö£º193191456" />
```

Note that the document itself claims to be encoded using gb2312.

I took a tour in the forum and realized that there may be some problems in the encoding definition.  If I try the following

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.jjwxc.net/onebook.php?    novelid=1485737').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.original_encoding
>> {windows-1252}
```

But

```
import chardet 
chardet.detect(html)
```

gives

```
>> {'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None}
```

Can someone shine some light onto this problem? Thank you!

I used the method mentioned in [how to decode and encode web page with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184863/how-to-decode-and-encode-web-page-with-python), and found that it worked with most Chinese websites but the one that I am interested in.

Comment: i checked that with splinter library, the data is in chinese and not broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should do the work.

> The GBK codec provides conversion to and from the Chinese GB18030/GBK/GB2312 encoding.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.jjwxc.net/onebook.php?novelid=1485737"
response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text
text = text.decode('gbk').encode('utf-8')
print text

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        <title>隆露拢篓脮媒掳忙拢漏卤录脭脗隆路脢帽驴脥_隆戮脭颅麓麓脨隆脣碌|脩脭脟茅脨隆脣碌隆驴_陆煤陆颅脦脛脩搂鲁脟</title>
...
...
```

Comment: @YeTian Did you copied everything? include the import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') ?

Comment: That's very interesting, since my computer is not printing out anything. I copied and pasted the code exactly as is.. BTW, 隆露拢篓脮媒掳忙拢漏卤录脭脗隆路脢帽驴脥_隆戮脭颅麓麓脨隆脣碌|脩脭脟茅脨隆脣碌隆驴_陆 is also gibberish, but far improved from what I have been getting.

Comment: can you use other libraries? like selenium or splinter? because with those libraries it works well.@YeTian

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the authority to install these libraries on the computer that I am using.