# scraping chinese characters python

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, decoding

I learnt how to scrap website from https://automatetheboringstuff.com. I wanted to scrap http://www.piaotian.net/html/3/3028/1473227.html in which the contents is in chinese and write its contents into a .txt file. However, the .txt file contains random symbols which I assume is a encoding/decoding problem.

I've read this thread "[how to decode and encode web page with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184863/how-to-decode-and-encode-web-page-with-python)" and figured the encoding method for my site is "gb2312" and "windows-1252". I tried decoding in those two encoding methods but failed.

Can someone kindly explain to me the problem with my code? I'm very new to programming so please let me know my misconceptions as well!

Also, when I remove the "html.parser" from the code, the .txt file turns out to be empty instead of having at least symbols. Why is this the case?

```
import bs4, requests, sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

novel = requests.get("http://www.piaotian.net/html/3/3028/1473227.html")
novel.raise_for_status()

novelSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(novel.text, "html.parser")

content = novelSoup.select("br")

novelFile = open("novel.txt", "w")
for i in range(len(content)):
    novelFile.write(str(content[i].getText()))
```

Comment: You just need to find the correct encoding on website and apply that. Here is the detailed tutorial on agenty - https://www.agenty.com/doc/hosted-app/248/scraping-chinese-or-japanese-websites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
novel = requests.get("http://www.piaotian.net/html/3/3028/1473227.html")
novel.raise_for_status()
novel.encoding = "GBK"
novelSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(novel.text, "html.parser")
```

out:

```
<br>
    一元宗，坐落在青峰山上，绵延极长，现在是盛夏时节，天空之中，太阳慢慢落了下去，夕阳将影子拉的很长。<br/>
<br/>
    一片不是很大的小湖泊边上，一个约莫着十七八岁的青衣少年坐在湖边，抓起湖边的一块石头扔出，顿时在湖边打出几朵浪花。<br/>
<br/>
    叶希文有些茫然，他没想到，他居然穿越了，原本叶希文只是二十一世纪的地球上一个普通的大学生罢了，一个月了，他才后知后觉的反应过来，这不是有人和他进行恶作剧，而是，他真的穿越了。<br/>
```

> Requests will automatically decode content from the server. Most
>   unicode charsets are seamlessly decoded.
>
> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the
>   encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding
>   guessed by Requests is used when you access r.text. You can find out
>   what encoding Requests is using, and change it, using the r.encoding
>   property:
>
> ```
> >>> r.encoding
> 'utf-8'
> >>> r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
> ```
>
> If you change the encoding, Requests will use the new value of
>   r.encoding whenever you call r.text.

Comment: Thanks for the working code! How did you figure out how to use the "GBK" though? And if I use this 'text = novel.text
text=text.decode("GBK").encode("utf-8")' why didn't it work?

Comment: 'GBK', 'gb2312' or 'utf-8'  , take a try, in most case, it will work. And do the encode part before you use .text.